# How to skip downstream jenkins job based on upstream job status code

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins upstream job `Job_A` which has a downstream job `Job_B`. Job_A returns a status code(10) if a file is not found in a specific directory. but I don't want Job_A to fail instead I want to skip the downstream job if upstream job exits with status code(10). Can someone help on how to do this ? I'm completely new to Jenkins.

Following is the high-level diagram.
[jenkins-job-condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYvEZ.png)

I have tried [Jenkin's conditional step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/conditional-buildstep/) but I'm unable to find a proper solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should define the condition on ***upstream*** job by adding `Build other projects` from Post-build Actions as following.

[image]